# What is the best way to create and edit a file from a bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which creates a brand new file. I want to populate that file with some commands. What is the best way to do that ?

```
test.sh has
sudo touch /tmp/myfile.txt
```

I want myfile.txt to have the following lines of text

```
Hello World!
Today is a good day!
```

....

How can I do that from test.sh ?

Comment: If you ever find you need to truncate a file to insure it is empty before a set of appends, `:> filename` will allow you to do that. (effectively redirects nothing to the new file -- truncating it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can echo and redirect output to your file by overwriting it:

```
echo "your text here" > myfile.txt
```

or appending it:

```
echo "your text here" >> myfile.txt
```

Comment: May be worth mentioning `printf` as an alternative to `echo` for output as it provides vastly more formatting control and can be used to write its formatted output to a variable in bash as well with the `-v` option.